# Boost accumulator memory usage and efficiency

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, accumulator

I'm using boost accumulators to get statistics from a vector of doubles in C++.
Each time I need a new statistic, I'm calling a custom method that gets it by creating the accumulator, loading it with the vector values and lastly using the boost statistic function eg.

```
double Entity::min(void) {
    accumulator_set< double, features< tag::min > > acc;
    // Now load the vector into the accumulator.
    acc = std::for_each( samples.begin(), samples.end(), acc );
    // Specify namespace to avoid name clash of this min method
    this->_min =  boost::accumulators::min(acc);
    return this->_min;
}
// etc. more methods for StdDev, mean, max etc.
```

My question is: does each creation of an accumulator in different methods duplicate (plus) the vector memory requirements? I know I could write a 'getStatstics' method which would get them all at once, but I'm wondering specifically if the creation and loading of an accumulator uses at least as much memory as the original vector each time its made.

Thanks guys

Pete

Comment: is `samples` an attribute of the class denoted by `this`?

Comment: Yes didierc, samples is a property of the Entity class, and is defined as a vector<double>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are using works on the `samples` collection, which is an attribute of the class `Entity`. The collection is an instance of the vector template.

The `std::for_each` instance works only on iterators of the collection, which are passed at construction time : `samples.begin()` and `samples.end()`.

Standard iterators are especially designed to abstract the notion of cursor or pointer on a collection. They do not duplicate the collection in any way, so you should not worry about memory allocation issue when using these.

The specific `accumulator_set` used here also doesn't produce any copy of the collection. It merely access the iterator, does a comparison between the current min candidate and the current pointed value of the collection, and keep the best of both for the next iteration.

As it stands, none of the standard parts you are using duplicates the collection.

Comment: Thanks alot didierc for the detailed answer - as I understand it, the iterator uses a cursor, and doesn't allocate more memory than is required for that cursor as it iterates of the vector<double>. So, memory impact is low, however processing is required to loop through the values. Thanks again Pete

Comment: no problem, given the nature of the code, I imagine you knew pretty much all of this, but I thought it would be a good thing to try giving as much details as possible. Hopefully I did not leave any gap in my explanations.